# notepadqq on ubuntu 22 on wsl deletes my file

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, notepadqq

I just installed Notepadqq v2.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and it gave the following message when attempting to load a file on my Google Drive:

`This file has been deleted from the file system.` with `Save` and `Ignore` options.

[image: NotepadqqErrorMsg]

If I ignore, a zero length file is opened. If I choose SAVE, a zero length file is opened and my original file is truncated to zero bytes. If I cancel out of the operation, all is well on my file but I have nothing to edit.

Weird thing is that I have narrowed this behavior down to the following.

- Open a DOS window in a directory with my file on Google Drive
- Execute bash to open up a WSL bash terminal.
- Attempt to open the file with Notepadqq.

Bug occurs.

If I click open a WSL prompt into my root directory and edit a file from there, Notepadqq seems to work correctly.

If I try this on the `/mnt/c` mount, Notepadqq seems to work correctly.

I have searched Google, searched Ask Ubuntu, and did an image search of the displayed image on Google image search. No joy with any of these.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Just to be clear, you're running in a WSL environment, and the application (Notepadqq) is generating an error in this environment? What's the output when you run `sudo notepadqq` on the command line? What about as a non-root user: `notepadqq`? Could be a permissions issue. Have you tried to reinstall the application?

Comment: I'm just not able to reproduce on WSL2 using Ubuntu 22.04 with Notepadqq 2.0-beta installed via `apt`.  Opening a file on the Windows drive works fine, with no message regarding deletion.  Some questions to help clarify - Does this happen with *any* file, or just this one particular one?  The `pipe.sav` file looks to be working normally from the tab color - Is that file on the root filesystem?

Comment: Also, is that a USB drive, flash drive, etc.?  Is the result any different if you use the `C:` drive (e.g. `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/forkwait.sav`)?

Comment: @richbl It will not run as root. Get message :

" Notepadqq will ask for root privileges whenever they are needed if either 'kdesu' or 'gksu' are installed. Running Notepadqq as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root if you really want to."

I did not allow it to contine. I get the original error with any file I open from a bash shell directly into a windows directory. It works fine when opened directly into my root directory but is very inconvenient, such that I don't use it.

I have not tried reinstalling it yet.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds This happens with all files I have tried. The pipe.sav file is one that it deleted so I started using a backup version to test with. I had it open in my root directory and it reopened automatically when I opened a copy from another directory. The one in root was not truncated. The other one was. I am on my G: drive. which is google drive. Not a usb stick or anything like that. Just went to my real C drive and did the same thing and it worked fine. Must be something to do with google drive.

Comment: @ClayD Good info!  I've edited it into the question itself, but would appreciate your review to make sure that looks correctly.  I'll see if I can reproduce based on the updated info.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That seems to about cover it

Comment: @ClayD I haven't had a chance to install Google Drive on one of my systems to see if this can be worked around.  It sounds like there's some conflict between the file-locking mechanism of Google Drive and the way that Notepadqq (and potentially other Linux applications) is operating.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I think you are right. Google drive does some odd stuff compared to most filesystems. Have to admit it is over my head though. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: My gut feeling is that [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1774272/1210833) is a similar (perhaps the same) root cause.